# How to Focus on the textbox that needs correction?

Tags: vb.net

i have a few textboxes for inputing values in, but i want a textbox to prompt me if I have made a mistake inputting values, as well as setting focus on that textbox with the mistake, how do I go about doing that? So far, I have

> Try
>
> ```
>        StuNames = CType(txtStuName.Text, String)
>        a1 = CType(txtA1.Text, Decimal)
>        a2 = CType(txtA2.Text, Decimal)
> ```
>
> Catch
>
> ```
>        MessageBox.Show("Please input a valid value!", "Error")
>
>       ?? txtA2.focus() ???
> ```
>
> End Try

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated,

thanks.

Comment: Did you try your code? Because I think it would work if you removed the question marks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
StuNames = txtStuName.Text
If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtA1.Text, a1) Then
    txtA1.Focus()
ElseIf Not Decimal.TryParse(txtA2.Text, a2) Then
    txtA2.Focus()
End If
```